# c does not have templates so will have to use void* function

Tags: c

For functions such as below, how can I make a void* function kinda like a c++ template. Ive done it before, but cant remember how to reconstruct it the right way.

```
float add(float a, float b)
{
 return a + b;
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
return a + b;
}
```

I think its almost something like

```
  void* fun(void *a)
{
    return (void*)a;
}
```

But the above does not work.
How can I fix the above.

Comment: Research `_Generic` .

Comment: void pointers should be avoided - why use them? Type safety....

Answer (score 1):

You can define a macro something like this.

```
#define add(x,y) ((x)+(y))
```

However, you should be careful while using macros since only text replacement happens after preprocessing. Ideally, inline functions should be preferred over macros.

You should read about [generic selections](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html) for your specific use case.

Comment: @phuclv Thanks for the note. I've updated the answer and highlighted potential issues.

Comment: Please try to avoid macros. Plays havoc when using a debugger